# Keep UIView fixed when attached to UIWindow in iOS8

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios8, uiwindow

Up until iOS7, if I wanted to create a sort of a fixed "background" that would not rotate, animate or scale whatsoever, I would have simply attached a UIView to the main UIWindow.
It was a kind of hack... but it served very well its purpose.

In iOS8 they changed the way UIWindow behave among other things (for example now `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` returns different size depending on the orientation).

Anyway...

My question is: how do I get iOS8 to behave as iOS7 and below?
I tried already to create two ViewControllers, one with `shouldAutorotate` method set to `NO` but with no luck.

The desired effect is the one shown here:

[image][image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you already set supportedInterfaceOrientations? Are your VCs created by code or IB? You also want to ensure that shouldAutorotate is getting hit in your controller code with a breakpoint.

Comment: Yes... I've already set supportedInterfaceOrientations (and actually one of the VC rotates correctly, it wouldn't otherwise). VC are created by code and shouldAutorotate gets hit but not honoured. Up until iOS 8 you could also obtain the desired effect with one single VC, by attaching the view that you wanted to keep fixed, to the main uiwindow.

Answer (score 0):

If you build your app using iOS8 SDK, you can use [nativeBounds](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html), which will always return bounds for portrait orientation, but in the pixels, not in the points.

To get right bounds in points you should divide them by `nativeScale`.

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(nativeBounds)]) {
    CGFloat scaleFactor = 1.0f / [self nativeScale];
    CGRect realBounds = CGRectApplyAffineTransform([self nativeBounds],
                                                   CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor));
}
```

So I think you can subscribe to didChangeStatusBarOrientation notification and in your method calculate new frame for green square and justify rotation:

```
rect.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)M_PI * (90.f) / 180.0f);
```

for landscape right orientation

Comment: Thanks for your input. However what I'm trying to achieve is to keep the view completely fixed... it's a different approach: I don't need it to "counter-rotate", I need it to stay where it is, unaffected by the device rotation (while everything else does).

Answer (score 0):

try to use this subclass with fixed rotation:

```c
@interface RotationView : UIView {
  struct {
    CGPoint portOrigin;
    CGPoint leftOrigin;
    CGPoint rightOrigin;
    CGPoint upsideOrigin;
  } origins;

  struct {
    NSInteger portDegree;
    NSInteger leftDegree;
    NSInteger rightDegree;
    NSInteger upsideDegree;
  } degrees;
}

@end

@implementation RotationView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
  [super didMoveToSuperview];

  UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
  if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    origins.portOrigin = self.frame.origin;
    origins.rightOrigin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinY(self.frame), CGRectGetWidth(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(self.frame));
    origins.leftOrigin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetHeight(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(self.frame), CGRectGetMinX(self.frame));
    origins.upsideOrigin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(self.frame),
                                       CGRectGetHeight(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(self.frame));

    degrees.portDegree = 0.0F;
    degrees.rightDegree = 270;
    degrees.leftDegree = 90.0F;
    degrees.upsideDegree = 180.0F;

  } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    origins.portOrigin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(self.frame),
                                     CGRectGetHeight(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(self.frame));
    origins.leftOrigin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinY(self.frame), CGRectGetWidth(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(self.frame));
    origins.rightOrigin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetHeight(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(self.frame), CGRectGetMinX(self.frame));
    origins.upsideOrigin = self.frame.origin;

    degrees.portDegree = 180.0F;
    degrees.rightDegree = 90.0F;
    degrees.leftDegree = 270;
    degrees.upsideDegree = 0.0F;

  } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    origins.upsideOrigin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetHeight(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(self.frame), CGRectGetMinX(self.frame));
    origins.leftOrigin = self.frame.origin;
    origins.rightOrigin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(self.frame),
                                      CGRectGetHeight(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(self.frame));
    origins.portOrigin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinY(self.frame), CGRectGetWidth(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(self.frame));

    degrees.upsideDegree = 90.0F;
    degrees.leftDegree = 0.0F;
    degrees.rightDegree = 180.0F;
    degrees.portDegree = 270.0;

  } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    origins.portOrigin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetHeight(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(self.frame), CGRectGetMinX(self.frame));
    origins.leftOrigin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(self.frame),
                                     CGRectGetHeight(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(self.frame));
    origins.rightOrigin = self.frame.origin;
    origins.upsideOrigin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinY(self.frame), CGRectGetWidth(self.superview.frame) - CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(self.frame));

    degrees.portDegree = 90.0F;
    degrees.leftDegree = 180.0F;
    degrees.rightDegree = 0.0F;
    degrees.upsideDegree = 270.0F;
  }
}

#pragma mark Manual oritentation change

#define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees * (float)M_PI) / 180.0f)

- (void)deviceOrientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
  if (!self.superview) {
    return;
  }

  if ([self.superview isKindOfClass:[UIWindow class]]) {
    [self setTransformForCurrentOrientation];
  }
}

- (void)setTransformForCurrentOrientation {
  UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

  if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
      [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(RADIANS(degrees.leftDegree))];
      [self setOrigin:origins.leftOrigin];
    } else {
      [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(RADIANS(degrees.rightDegree))];
      [self setOrigin:origins.rightOrigin];
    }
  } else {
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
      [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(RADIANS(degrees.upsideDegree))];
      [self setOrigin:origins.upsideOrigin];
    } else {
      [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(RADIANS(degrees.portDegree))];
      [self setOrigin:origins.portOrigin];
    }
  }
}

@end
```

setOrigin is category method:

```c
- (void)setX:(CGFloat)x {
  CGRect frame = self.frame;
  frame.origin.x = x;
  self.frame = frame;
}

- (void)setY:(CGFloat)y {
  CGRect frame = self.frame;
  frame.origin.y = y;
  self.frame = frame;
}
- (void)setOrigin:(CGPoint)origin {
  [self setX:origin.x];
  [self setY:origin.y];
}
```